# What is the best platform-neutral font for résumés?

Tags: fonts

Which font is the best to make a résumé look equally good on all operating systems?

Answer (score 15):

Why not convert the resume to a PDF so that it looks the same across the different OS's?

Comment: PDF is just the best, I'm a web developer/designer and the resume on my website is only available as a PDF, I don't bother making a HTML version and creating HTML is my job.  This is not laziness, it's because PDF is the only way to know it's shown as intended.

Comment: Many places don't accept PDF resumes. Word or plain-text only.

Comment: I suppose you have to be prepared for the business that does not accept PDF; however, in my experience those are a relatively small percentage and they are more likely not to accept it electronically at all.

Comment: If a place doesn't accept PDF, it's probably not worth working there. There is absolutely no benefit asking for a Word document over a PDF. I submitted my resume in PDF to a recruitment agency that asked for Word or plain-text only and I still got the job.

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft Core Fonts like Arial, Verdana, Tahoma and Times New Roman are usually available on most platforms, but there's no guarantee that any font is available on any platform. The best thing to do is use a document format that preserves font information such as PDF, which is an open-spec file format with at least primitive viewers available on the most widely used platforms.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be completely platform neutral then you should format it in plain text and wrap it at 80 columns. Otherwise, even if you end up using Times New Roman which is available on nearly every platform but put it in a Word document, you'll be restricted.

Comment: Plain text is also specifically requested by many recruiters and HR departments as the only acceptable alternative to Word, so it's good to have around.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly and boringly Times New Roman for printed / pdf documents.

Or are you asking about a font for web delivery? It's hard to tell with the lack of any real information in your question.